# how to create trigger on select in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I want to add +1 for *views* column when a visitor view a page. I decided to make it using trigger, but i don't know how to make a trigger on select, I see examples on `delete`, `update` and `insert` but no one mentioned `select`. anyone can help me with simple example?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a trigger for 'SELECT' in SQL Server. As an alternative you could create a stored procedure that does the SELECT and UPDATEs your view counts.

Answer (score 0):

short answer is no,there is nothing like trigger on SELECT.moreover 
If the data you have if so sensitive and you want to implement access audit in t-sql (which not the best design idea), you can do the following:

1. Remove SELECT access to the table from all users

   2. Create stored procedure to retrieve data from the table
   3. Implement custom audit inside of the above stored proc.

you can view this link [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/898089/introduction-of-trigger-in-sql-server-2012/) to read about it more